# Converting a very small python Decimal into a non-scientific notation string

Tags: python, floating-point

I am using the Python Decimal class for precise floating-point arithmetic. I need to convert the result number consistently into a standard notation number as a string. However, very small decimal numbers are rendered in scientific notation by default.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> 
>>> d = Decimal("0.000001")
>>> d
Decimal('0.000001')
>>> str(d)
'0.000001'
>>> d = Decimal("0.000000001")
>>> d
Decimal('1E-9')
>>> str(d)
'1E-9'
```

How would I get `str(d)` to return `'0.000000001'`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
'{:f}'.format(d)
Out[12]: '0.000000001'
```

Comment: It's interesting that `.format` uses full precision while `%f` defaults to a precision of 6

Comment: Good comment. I've checked and in fact documentation states that default precision is 6, both in docs for [python2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) and [python3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: with f-strings it looks like this: `f"{d:f}"`